# Ajax Page Refreshes (barba.js) and POST forms - no "resubmit the for form"

Tags: javascript, ajax, typo3, http-post, barbajs

I'm purely working on the frontend of a website and for smoother page-transitions and a better flow I used the [barba.js](https://barba.js.org/) library which I find very easy to use and super cool.

All is fine but one thing.

The backend for this project will be implemented in Typo3 and the backend team has to use POST for all forms.

Usually if a POST form is submitted and you're on the new page and hit Refresh (F5, Cmd-R, whatever) the browser asks you if you want to "Resubmit the form" in a prompt/dialogue.

However with the barba ajax page-load this is not happening and is throwing a typo3 error on refresh on the new page.

So the form-submission works fine, but once on the resultspage for a POST-form, when hitting refresh it always throws an error as headers are probably not sent.

[image]

Any idea on how to address this? What is causing this?

Comment: Use browser's console to check what exactly pages are loaded after form submitted with what payload. It looks like it doesn't passes arguments to next view (also POST sent forms shouldn't be refreshed by hand ever) The common solution is redirecting in your controller to some GET view (i.e. *Thank you page*) right after submitting the form and handling its data.

Comment: We're programmers, we can read. Please read about [why you shouldn’t upload images of code or errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can check if argument(s) exists with:

```
$this->request->hasArgument('name'){
    try...
}
```

However it looks like it doesn't passes arguments to next view. Keep in mind that POST sent forms shouldn't be refreshed by hand ever to avoid such situations. The common solution is redirecting in your controller to some GET view (i.e. *Thank you page*) right after submitting the form and handling its data.

In controller's action you can redirect it by:

```
$this->redirect('thankYouPage'); // will redirect to `thankYouPageAction` in the same controller
```

or

```
$this->redirectToUri('uri/to/some/existing/thank-you-page')
```